# Send Email Asp.Net Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net, email, smtp

I want to send email with my html template and i have my cshtml template with model but i can't convert it to string for email body :

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.To.Add(to);
mail.Subject = subject;
mail.Body = ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **MimeMessage** instead of **MailMessage**

How to work with it is as follows.

```
var emailMessage = new MimeMessage();
emailMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(MailConfig.FromName, MailConfig.FromAddress));
emailMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(toName, toAddress));
emailMessage.Subject = subject;
emailMessage.Body = new TextPart(TextFormat.Html) {Text = body};
```

As you can see, **TextPart** class is used to set the Body value.